# iOS UIPageViewController Spine Location

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I`m implementing an UIPageViewController and all works fine even if i rotate the device after the initialization it sets the SpineLocation correctly, BUT

When i Instantiate the UIPageViewController, IF the device is on landscape orientation it creates the UIPageViewController with just one page (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin)...

I`m trying to instantiate it using UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid just like the code below (and like developer.apple recommends) BUT when i do it... the UIPageViewController doesn`t load...

```
NSDictionary * options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid]
forKey:UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey];

UIPageViewController *pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc]
initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl
  navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                options:options]
```

Is there something wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use this delegate.

```
- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController  *)pageViewController
               spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation))
{
 //Set the array with only 1 view controller
    UIViewController *currentViewController = [self.pageController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:currentViewController];
    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];

    //Important- Set the doubleSided property to NO.
    self.pageController.doubleSided = NO;
    //Return the spine location
    return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin;

 }

else
{
NSArray *viewControllers = nil;

    exampleViewController *currentViewController = [self.pageController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

    NSUInteger currentIndex = [self.VControllers indexOfObject:currentViewController];

    if(currentIndex == 0 || currentIndex %2 == 0)
    {
        UIViewController *nextViewController = [self pageViewController:self.pageController viewControllerAfterViewController:currentViewController];
        viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:currentViewController, nextViewController, nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIViewController *previousViewController = [self pageViewController:self.pageController viewControllerBeforeViewController:currentViewController];
        viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:previousViewController, currentViewController, nil];
    }
    //Now, set the viewControllers property of UIPageViewController
    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];

    return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid;
}
}
```